# Cleaning down phone between uses?

Tags: photos, video, delete

I'm project manager consulting for a charity who have a set of LG Nexus phones that are sent into schools as part of a STEM project.  For safeguarding reasons when the phones are returned we need to clear off any photos, videos, audio recordings and any internet cache/history.  There are a couple of apps loaded onto the phones for the students to use that need to be retained.

I'm looking for a fast solution for cleaning the phones.  All the phones are connected to the same Gmail account.

I know nothing about coding for Android devices (or anything about Android devices in truth!) so please be kind with your responses.

Many thanks in advance.

Julia

Comment: So it's just the apps (and probably the Google account) that need to be installed to a "sanitized" device? Or must the apps already be pre-configured somehow? Also, are the devices rooted? Do they have a custom recovery? Choices differ based on those facts.

Comment: Hi Izzy, I don't believe the devices are rooted.  The apps that are used do not need to store any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data of the apps that need to be retained is not important, a fast-but-dirty solution would be to integrate those apps into the system partition. That way the phones' data will easily be erasable via a factory reset, but the apps you need will stay installed on the device. That way the only thing left to do after the reset is re-connect the phones to your Google account.

To "convert" apps into system apps, however, one would require root permissions (and possibly unlocking the bootloader), [which *may* void the warranty of the phones based on where you live/where those phones were bought. (In the EU, for example, the warranty would remain intact.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android_OS)#Legality) Truth be told there are dozens of "quick but sloppy" ways to achieve this but I don't think any of them apply for your use case.

Another way I can think of that does not require root is to trust Google's cloud device backup -- Since Android 6.0 (Marshmallow), a device's apps and apps' data, WiFi connections etc. are periodically uploaded into the cloud so that, if a customer buys a new device (or resets their current one), the Setup Wizard that launches at first boot can offer to restore the data that was previously backed up. Sadly (though understandably), this only works for applications that are installed off the Play Store. The downside of this method is that a) you'll still have to connect the devices to the Play Store, and that b) the backup functionality only works periodically, so the data that ends up getting restored might be several days old. There are other ways to back up and restore data on an Android device (sadly my reputation won't allow me to post a link, but a quick online search for 'android backup tool' will do the trick) but those are, again, cumbersome and sometimes unreliable.

I've heard some good things about [Google Classroom](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6118412?hl=en), but I don't know if it supports wiping devices, or if it fits into the scope of your project.

Comment: Thank you Jari, I will look into those options you have suggested.

Comment: @Julez won't work for you: integrating apps into the system partition would require root – which you said is not a given.

Answer (score 0):

As root is not available, there might be another viable approach by just clearing the app data. For some background, please take a look at our [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) and [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info). The idea, in short, is walking all apps and clearing their data:

```
adb shell "pm list packages"
```

would list all installed apps. It can be restricted to just the user-installed apps by adding another parameter, `-3` (3=third-party). Next to that, the `pm` tool a.o. allows to "clear app data" for a given app:

```
adb shell "pm clear com.package.name"
```

The package name you need here is returned by the `list packages` command from above. So you'd need to create a script once, calling `pm clear` for each app you want to clear the data from (you certainly want to skip some, e.g. to have the Google account remain intact). Then, whenever you need to "clean devices", simply connect the device to your computer via USB cable and run the script.

Comment: Thanks for that information.  I really know nothing about how to interact with these devices but I will make it my business to find out how and try that script you mentioned  :-)

Comment: Our tag-wikis will be a good starting point (here, especially the already mentioned [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info)). You might be interested in the "minimal installation of ADB" (as you certainly don't need a full-fledged development environment), and a "basic dive" into ADB commands. You won't regret it, as ADB comes in handy with many situations (eg. accessing the logs, see our [logging tag-wiki](/tags/logging/info)). Good luck, and let us know if this worked for you then, @Julez !